# Need assistance padding numerical month and day with leading 0

Tags: date, vbscript, batch-file

I am working within a batch file and need to pad a single digit with a leading 0 if under 10.  I have the values in environmental variables.  They are month and day, I need to pad to match file structure I am working against.  I am using vbscript to return a date that comes back in the following format "7/16/2009".  Need it to look like "07/16/2009" and most inportantly need each item in separate EVs.

VBscript:

```
WScript.Echo DateAdd("d", Date, -36)
```

Batch:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ('cscript //nologo get36thday.vbs') do (
   SET YYYY=%%z
   SET MM=%%x
   SET DD=%%y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the batch script, I don't know the *exact* syntax but a batch script can return a specified number of characters from the *right* side of a string.

So, append the month after a "0" character and take the 2 right-most digits. It would probably look something similar to this:

```
SET MM=0%%x
SET MM=%MM:~-2%
```

1 become 01
5 becomes 05
10 stays 10

Comment: +1. Nice trick. I would have used a subroutine and an `if` statement. But this is much more elegant.

Answer (score 9):

VBScript:

```
dteOldDate = Now()
strNewDate = Right("00" & Month(dteOldDate), 2) & "/" & Right("00" & Day(dteOldDate), 2) & "/" & Year(dteOldDate)
```

Comment: You also need to echo the date: `WScript.Echo strNewDate`, because the batch file reads it from the script's output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method of padding strings.

In this example, MYVAR will be padded to five zeroes.

```
SET MYVAR=00000%MYVAR%
SET MYVAR=%MYVAR:~-5%
```

Answer (score 0):

Athough the other answers are useful if you don't know the length of the string you want to pad with zeros up front, for dates and times a simple string replacement will do.

```
set hour=!TIME:~0,2!
set hour=!hour: =0!
```

In short, if there is a space it will be replaced by a 0.